# Slim Framework always return void 200OK

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I have a web poject in a GoDaddy shared host. Is a webpage with an APIrest made with Slim Framework. This is the structure:

```
public_html/
    - index.html (main webpage)
    - css, js, ...
    test/
        include/
            - database handler, connection, etc
        rest/
            - index.php (API)
            - .htaccess
            Slim/ (framework files)
```

The .htaccess is the original:

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The PHP version is the same on local server and the host (5.4).

The problem is that in local server works perfect, but when I put it in the host not. If I try the example:

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
```

I get a status 200 OK with void body. Any idea where is the problem? Thanks

**Edit:**

When change .htacces like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I always get status 404 not found

Comment: Anything in your error logs?

Comment: Hmm, [seems similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668693/slim-no-response-data). Not sure, really - does this host give you any control panels to change PHP (e.g. version or Apache handler type)? I'd tinker with that, if so.

Comment: Enable PHP errors and check if `.htaccess` is supported. I guess the errors are disabled in a production environment.

Comment: First try would be to use correct RewriteBase which in your case should be  /test/rest/